# VBA Looping through excel files in selected directory - Copy data and paste in different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to select a directory and then loop through each xlsm file within that directory. For each loop it should open the file, copy a range and paste into the current workbook under a specific sheet.

I.e. the first file will paste into sheet1 the second opened file will past into sheet 2, and so on.

I have some code, now I need help to get it to paste the rang into a sheets.count? or something like that. At the moment it just pastes into sheet 1 because that is static.

```
Sub Test()


Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Set wb1 = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xlsm"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

 'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
  'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Copy data from opened workbook
  wb.Sheets("HI Sub-segment split").Range("A1:Z1").Copy

'Paste data into destination workbook
  wb1.Sheet(1).Range("A1:Z1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Close Workbook
  wb.Close

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
 Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "Import Complete!"

 ResetSettings:

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Place `wb1.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` between the Copy and PasteSpecial lines.  The command will set the new sheet as the active one so the PasteSpecial will now have to be to the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved it as following...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with this...

```
Sub Testing()

'
'
'

Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim loop_ctr As Integer

 Set wb1 = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
 loop_ctr = 1


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Copy data from opened workbook
  wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Copy

'Paste data into destination workbook
  wb1.Sheets(loop_ctr).Range("A1:B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Close Workbook
  wb.Close

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir

'Update loop_ctr value
  loop_ctr = loop_ctr + 1
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "Import Complete!"

ResetSettings:

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```